# Apache: Authentification before proxing

Tags: apache, authentication, proxy, virtualhost, proxypass

I got a VM with a aplication running on it. It doenst support password protection. I connect to it like sub.domain.com:6000 (redirecting port 6000 to 80 of VM)

So i like to use apache as a Proxy with authentication.

My VirtualHost config:

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/

<Directory "/var/www">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Restricted Content"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
</Directory>

ProxyPass "/" "http://127.0.0.1:5000/"
ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://127.0.0.1:5000/"

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

It redirects me, but there is no password protection.
What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<Directory>` directive is used to enclose a group of directives that will apply only to the named directory, sub-directories of that directory, and the files within the respective directories. Proxied server is none of that, so you have to use `<Location>` directive which limits the scope of the enclosed directives by URL:

```
<Location />
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Restricted Content"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```